# Why do we need incubation time during the glucose test by chronoamperometry?

Tags: electrochemistry

Also, is there any difference between with and without incubation time in the glucose test? For example, the voltage results acquired will be different?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion . In chronoamperometry, you measure voltage and not currrent. Also, there are so many different glucose sensing procedures. Could you summarize the particular one you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Well, Although I'm not a chemical student, I think I could share my understand of the Chronoamperometry by the parameters that could affect the result in my project.

According to my test result, the incubation time will affect the magnitude of the current response at the chemical cell(also for the trigger time). This is related to the property of the glucose test strip(Truetrack in my design) and the circuit design. And I assume that this is because of the distribution of the glucose in the test strip, specially the amount of the glucose close to the surface of the electrode.

I hope if there is a chemical guy that can explain the detailed principle of Chronoamperometry, very detailed stuff. Because I have finished my project and thus the theoretical staff used for the lecture is not enough to attract my attention.
Also, if someone has interest in this, I can share my experiment result and discuss with him personally. 
Here is my email: matthew97829782@gmail.com